# Zoom to fit all visible markers

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3

Is it possible to have maps zoom to show all visible markers within viewport?

I have a JavaScript search functionality which shows/hides map markers on client side.

What I would like is the possibility to automatically re-zoom so that all the current visible map markers is not clung together and is not outside the viewport.

Any chance this is possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you have to do is create a LatLngBounds object, extend that with all the points from the markers and use fitBounds with your new bounds object.

```
var map, markers;
var bounds = google.maps.LatLngBounds();
for (var marker in markers) {
    if (markers.hasOwnProperty(marker) && marker.getVisible() === true) {
        bounds.extend(marker.getPosition());
    }
}
map.fitBounds(bounds);
```

Comment: Wow, thanks for the code :) Ill test it out right away.

Comment: You're welcome. Don't forget to mark the question as solved if it worked for you.